# Constructing an NFA that is equivalent to a regular expression

Tags: regular-expressions, nondeterminism

I am a little stuck at attempting to give an NFA for the regular expression $0^+(10^+0)^∗$
, where the alphabet is ${0, 1}$. I have tried to construct multiple NFA's state diagram and the closest I can come up with is [image]

However, I see that this NFA also accepts $0^+(10^+0)^∗0^*$. Is there any way I can alter this state diagram so that it only recognizes $0^+(10^+0)^∗$? I feel that I am missing something simple here...

Comment: Add a new state $q_3$, and create a transition between $q_0$ to it, when you read the value $0$

Comment: Aren’t those regular expressions equivalent?